Ubuntu 24.04 installation with TPM FDE - "Enhanced secure boot options cannot currently install third party drivers"
I got the following message from subiquity when attempting to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 24. Weirdly enough this does not seem to be an issue when I remove the "Install third-party software..." option for the installation. Does any dev know what is going on here and why I'm unable to install third party drivers with TPM FDE?

Which third party drivers?  Were you asked to generate/install any MOK keys (for self signing the drivers)? Have you considered turning off the secure boot/tpm security features in your UEFI settings?

Hey! I'm talking about the installation wizard, there is an option to install "third party drivers" - the exact drivers installed in this process idk (nvidia + intel proprietary drivers I would guess), but I don't really understand why this should affect OS signatures. IMO seems like a bug/deficiency but I'm an expert in that field
